# Selenium failing on AWS-batch

Tags: amazon-web-services, selenium, selenium-webdriver, geckodriver, aws-batch

I am running a python script that implements selenium and geckodriver to login to a website account. The code works locally in a container with no problems, however when I deploy it to AWS-batch it stops working reliably.

I run this job at a scheduled time every morning, it works some days but mostly it will fail. The error occurs when I get to this piece of code:

```
driver.find_element_by_class_name(submit_button_name).click()

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 600)

wait.until(lambda driver: driver.current_url != login_url)
```

After it reaches the wait condition, it just waits until it runs out of time and the job fails. I checked the geckodriver logs and the redirect after submitting the login details never occurs, it just stays on the same page with the login details.

The code itself seems to work fine, its deploying it to aws-batch that is causing the issues

I have tried:

- Increasing the wait times of the conditions.
- Ensuring geckodriver and firefox versions are compatible.
- Running the job at different times of day.
- Added conditions to check for the presence of the submissions button etc.

Is there something I could be missing when it comes to deploying selenium tests to ec2 instances? Do I need to provision particular resources to run these tests? What could cause this job to succeed sometimes and not others?

Comment: can you ensure that if your timeout needs to be in seconds or milliseconds

Comment: Hi, the timeout is in seconds, this job will run for up to 12mins before a time out. I don't believe thats the problem here, as the job will succeed some days and fail others, when it does succeed it needs nowhere near the 12 mins allowed.

Comment: In that case there is an issue with the lamba function which you've written. Try alternative approaches to wait for the right url

Answer (score 0):

Based on your description &  the test is related to the Login section, while it's running fine locally and failed on AWS Batch, so i'm think of the high potential root cause that the resource (EC2 instance) having the right role, so it can be executed without being blocked by the page ( firewall)? Because sometimes the website firewall will detect if there's a bot browsing the page (which is from geckodriver, chromedriver, etc), so it will cache the page or block the container from being executed. So make sure you're having the right role for your EC2 instance (IAM role) & also trying to check if there's any thing that the firewall can prevent your container from being running properly ?